# Tanh property: mapping outlier values toward the mean : What do we mean by this?

Tags: neural-networks

I was reading Jurafsky 3rd edition, page 4 chapter 7

[image]

How does it map outlier to a value towards the mean? (This is not clear to me)

Here is the [link](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Ejurafsky/slp3/7.pdf) to the book chapter(freely available from the official author).

Comment: The highlighted comment refers to the fact that $\tanh$ decreases differences: for any numbers $x$ and $y,$ $\tanh(x)$ and $\tanh(y)$ are closer to each other than $x$ and $y$ are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to log-transfrom. If you take the log of log-normal distributed data, you will observe tail values shrink towards mean and it becomes normal distrb.. Below the behaviour of Tanh, where straight line represents original data and the other one tanh transformation. You can see edge values shrinked towards 0 which is the mean:

[image]